# Compiled function error - nontensor object created

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I'm trying to optimize code that uses Position MANY times.

The following toy code works:

```
list1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, 500000];
list2 = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {3, 500}];

test = ParallelTable[
        Flatten[
          Map[
            Position[list1, #] &, list2[[i]]
          ]
         ], {i, 1,  Length[list2]}];
```

My trouble begins because I have so much data to process. When I use my actual data in the code above, Mathematica takes 34 minutes to complete the computation.  This is just too long to be practical, so I began exploring Compile.

When I try this:

```
  test2 = 
    Compile[{{list1, _Integer, 1}, {list2, _Integer, 2}}, 
      Table[
        Flatten[
           Map[
              Position[list1, #] &, list2[[i]]
           ]
        ], {i, 1, Length[list2]}]];

   wow = test2[list1, list2]

 CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.
```

You can see that Mathematica complains.

My questions are:

1. How can I debug what the problem is in the Compiled statement above?  I really don't know how to start figuring out the problem.
2. Is there an obvious alternative to using Position that itself would be faster than Position?

I am not new to Mathematica, but I admit to being completely new to compiling code.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will try to address the second question you asked, since the first one has been answered already. The following code will not win a beauty contest, but will speed up your code 800 times for your test list sizes (note that I will use `Table` in place of `ParellelTable` in your code, since `ParallelTable` gives some really wrong results for your tests on my machine).

This is a massive binary search function, which takes a sorted list and a list of elements, and returns a list of position pairs for minimal and maximal position of an element in a list:

```
ClearAll[bsearchMassiveC];
bsearchMassiveC =
  Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}, {elems, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{n0 = 1, n1 = Length[list], m = 0, 
      res = Table[{-1,-1}, {Length[elems]}], ctr = 0, found = False
     },
     Do[
       found = False;
       n0 = 1;
       n1 = Length[list];
       m = 0;
       While[n0 <= n1, m = Floor[(n0 + n1)/2];
         If[list[[m]] == elem,
            n0 = n1 = m;
            While[n0 > 0 && list[[n0]] == elem , n0--];
            While[n1 <= Length[list] && list[[n1]] == elem , n1++];
            res[[++ctr]] = {n0 + 1, n1 - 1};
            found = True;
            Break[]
         ];
         If[list[[m]] < elem, n0 = m + 1, n1 = m - 1]
       ];
       If[! found, res[[++ctr]] = {-1,-1};], 
       {elem, elems}
     ];
     Take[res, ctr]
   ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

For example,

```
bsearchMassiveC[{1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,6,6,6,7,7,7,7},{1,3,5,7}]

(*  {{1,3},{6,6},{-1,-1},{12,15}}  *)
```

This is the main function. We first sort the list, then find positions in a sorted list, and finally reconstruct the positions in the original list:

```
ClearAll[getPositions];
getPositions[list_, elems_] :=
  With[{ord = Ordering[list]},
    With[{sorted = list[[ord]]},
      Table[
         ord[[Flatten[Range @@@ Select[
              bsearchMassiveC [sorted, elems[[i]]],
              # != {-1, -1} &]]
         ]],
         {i, Length[elems]}]]];
```

Here are the benchmarks:

```
list1=RandomInteger[{1,10000},500000];
list2=RandomInteger[{1,10000},{3,500}];

(res1= getPositions[list1,list2]);//AbsoluteTiming

(*   {0.1035157,Null}   *)

(res2 = 
    Table[Flatten[Map[Position[list1,#]&,list2[[i]]]],i,1,Length[list2]}]
 );//AbsoluteTiming

 (*  {82.6718750,Null}  *)

res1==res2

(*  True  *)
```

I did not attempt to parallelize my code, but I think it should be possible. Again, my attempts to use your code verbatim with `ParallelTable` resulted in wrong results. It would be good if others could confirm it, and even better to understand the reason behind it.

Comment: +1, binary search is the obvious solution but I just got time now and apparently it's too late :)

Comment: @acl Thanks:). I didn't have much time for SE recently, but today I had some, and the temptation was too high. I voted for your answer too, right after I posted mine.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the returned object would have been ragged, and `Compile` can't deal with that.

To see it's ragged, you try running it for smaller inputs and look at the output (even though `Compile` complains, you do get the output obtained by calling the uncompiled code):

```
list1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, 500]; 
list2 = RandomInteger[{1, 10000}, {3, 50}];
f[list1, list2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And to see that `Compile` can't deal with ragged arrays, try to construct a list of (lists with different lengths):

```
Compile[{}, 
  Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, RandomInteger[{0, 10}]], {i, 1, 10}]][]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

while if the sublists are of the same length, no complaints:

```
Compile[{}, Table[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 2], {i, 1, 10}]][]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'll not get into speeding this up.

Answer (score 4):

This is not as fast as Leonid's code, but runs in about 2.5 seconds without using `Compile`. It uses an indexing scheme based on the fact that `list1` is composed of integers within a relatively small range. A new list `L1` is created such that the element `L1[[n]]` contains a list of the positions of the value `n` in `list1`.

```
test2 = Module[{L1},
   L1 = ConstantArray[{}, {10000}];
   MapIndexed[(L1[[#]] = {L1[[#]], #2}) &, list1];
   L1 = Flatten /@ L1;
   Flatten /@ Map[L1[[#]] &, list2, {2}]];
```

Comment: A nice one, +1. I also often use such "hashing" schemes, but for some reasons this did not occur to me here.

Comment: while generally I'd go for binary search, this is clever